# Parsing CSV data into Activerecord(MySQL) is too slow and takes HOURS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm currently developing a custom ticket system for internal purposes for which I've written a RAILS application for. The ticket data is sourced from another location for which I can only get daily CSV extracts from. I've written a task that FTP's the CSV file locally and then runs the below task to import it into a MySQL DB using ActiveRecord.

However it is extremely slow! Each CSV file I get each day contains approximately 20,000-40,000 rows with a total data size of 8-10MB. Each row contains a ticket that has been created *or* modified in the past day, which explains why I'm checking to see if the ticket already exists in the code below.

Running in production mode without debug output doesn't make much of the difference.

```
desc 'Takes Orion csv file and parses into DB.'
    task :importcsv, [:local_file_path] => :environment do |t, args|
        require 'csv'
        @error_count = 0
        @success_count = 0

        csv = CSV.read(args.local_file_path, col_sep: ",", encoding: "ISO8859-1", headers: true)

        csv.each do |row|
            if(/PR(.*)/.match(row[0])? true : false) # Skip PR tickets because they're a waste of space right now
                @error_count += 1
                next
            end

            if(row[0] == " ") # Break loop if ticketid is just whitespace
                break
            end

            if(row[0].empty?) # Break loop if no ticketid
                break
            end

            ticket = Ticket.find_or_create_by_ticketid(row[0],  :severity => row[7],
                                                                :status => row[1],
                                                                :causecode => row[17],
                                                                :title => row[25],
                                                                :reportergrp => row[18],
                                                                :resolvergrp => row[5],
                                                                :resolvername => row[27],
                                                                :opendate => row[14],
                                                                :closedate => row[13],
                                                                :accountname => row[23],
                                                                :resolutiondesc => row[26] )

            @success_count += 1
        end
        Rails.logger.info " #{@success_count} out of #{@error_count + @success_count} tickets were added or updated."
    end
```

Here is a sample of the development debug output:

```
############### START PARSING ORION DATA ###############
Fetching data for date 2012-02-01...
    Data already exists locally. Did not download.
    Adding data to DB...
  [1m[36mTicket Load (99.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = '03052019' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mTicket Exists (24.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = BINARY '03052019' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (1.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `tickets` (`accountname`, `causecode`, `closedate`, `created_at`, `opendate`, `reportergrp`, `resolutiondesc`, `resolvergrp`, `resolvername`, `severity`, `status`, `ticketid`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('WESTPAC', 'AP_DATA', '2010-12-30 00:00:00', '2012-02-21 04:55:09', '2010-05-19 00:00:00', 'HDNZ', '-', 'DINZ', 'Sam Gardner', 3, 'CLOSED', '03052019', 'HTML GENERATED REPORTS CONT. OF FAULT: 03042', '2012-02-21 04:55:09')
  [1m[36m (2.3ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35mTicket Load (69.1ms)[0m  SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = '03089753' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mTicket Exists (19.8ms)[0m  SELECT 1 FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = BINARY '03089753' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.9ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `tickets` (`accountname`, `causecode`, `closedate`, `created_at`, `opendate`, `reportergrp`, `resolutiondesc`, `resolvergrp`, `resolvername`, `severity`, `status`, `ticketid`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('WESTPAC', 'SW_PROGRAMCODE', NULL, '2012-02-21 04:55:09', '2010-07-20 00:00:00', 'HDNZ', '-', 'IANZ', 'Mitch Bell', 3, 'RESTORED', '03089753', 'CEE: EDS ERROR', '2012-02-21 04:55:09')[0m
  [1m[35m (1.7ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36mTicket Load (66.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = '03236150' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mTicket Exists (21.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = BINARY '03236150' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `tickets` (`accountname`, `causecode`, `closedate`, `created_at`, `opendate`, `reportergrp`, `resolutiondesc`, `resolvergrp`, `resolvername`, `severity`, `status`, `ticketid`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('WESTPAC', 'AP_DATA', '2011-12-12 00:00:00', '2012-02-21 04:55:09', '2011-03-04 00:00:00', 'HDNZ', '-', 'DINZ', 'Liam Fitzpatrick', 3, 'CLOSED', '03236150', 'SAMETIME CONNECTION ISSUES', '2012-02-21 04:55:09')
  [1m[36m (1.5ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35mTicket Load (64.5ms)[0m  SELECT `tickets`.* FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = '03261509' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mTicket Exists (20.8ms)[0m  SELECT 1 FROM `tickets` WHERE `tickets`.`ticketid` = BINARY '03261509' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `tickets` (`accountname`, `causecode`, `closedate`, `created_at`, `opendate`, `reportergrp`, `resolutiondesc`, `resolvergrp`, `resolvername`, `severity`, `status`, `ticketid`, `title`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('WESTPAC', ' ', NULL, '2012-02-21 04:55:09', '2011-05-08 00:00:00', 'OPSNZ', '-', 'ANNZ', 'Anusha Konduti', 3, 'OPEN', '03261509', 'P2PTSM002:-INFOMAN ONLY (TONZ): ANR2578W SCHEDULE WEEKLY_SYS', '2012-02-21 04:55:09')[0m
  [1m[35m (1.4ms)[0m  COMMIT
```

Comment: Have you considered importing the CSV straight into MySQL, cleaning it up using SQL, and then copying the cleaned up stuff to its final location? I like Ruby but MySQL will be a lot faster at data wrangling.

Comment: I don't disagree with what you're saying. However I'd like to try to keep it all within the one package if possible - That is to say I'd like to keep it isolated to the RAILS app.

Comment: You can execute arbitrary SQL from inside Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out for whatever reason InnoDB was just taking an extremely long time. I switched to iSAM and it completely MUCH faster.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try bulk inserting rows into the database instead of single row inserts. I've had some good luck with increased performance using this method.

There is a really good gem for this called [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). Just collect all of your new objects into an array and at the end of your loop, bulk insert them.

Comment: Oh nice! I'll certainly give this a go. I had figured something like this would be the solution since its currently extremely loop heavy.

Comment: One thing with my data is that some rows contain a new ticket, whilst others will be a ticket I've already added but has updated data. Will a bulk INSERT automatically overwrite the data?

Comment: I believe there is an option to synchronize existing records, but I don't personally have experience with that. Check the source [here](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/blob/master/lib/activerecord-import/synchronize.rb)